# display 3 items in carousel - used existing pen

Tags: javascript

I found a pen online to create image carousel, problem is I can't get it display 3 items inside a container.

I have tried removing the opacity for the carousel photo but then it messes up the display for the full container.

Here is link to my fiddle:

```js
!(function(d) {
    // Variables to target our base class,  get carousel items, count how many carousel items there are, set the slide to 0 (which is the number that tells us the frame we're on), and set motion to true which disables interactivity.
    var itemClassName = "carousel__photo";
    items = d.getElementsByClassName(itemClassName),
        totalItems = items.length,
        slide = 0,
        moving = false;

    // To initialise the carousel we'll want to update the DOM with our own classes
    function setInitialClasses() {

        // Target the last, initial, and next items and give them the relevant class.
        // This assumes there are three or more items.
        items[totalItems - 1].classList.add("prev");
        items[0].classList.add("active");
        items[1].classList.add("next");
    }

    // Set click events to navigation buttons

    function setEventListeners() {
        var next = d.getElementsByClassName('carousel__button--next')[0],
            prev = d.getElementsByClassName('carousel__button--prev')[0];

        next.addEventListener('click', moveNext);
        prev.addEventListener('click', movePrev);
    }

    // Disable interaction by setting 'moving' to true for the same duration as our transition (0.5s = 500ms)
    function disableInteraction() {
        moving = true;

        setTimeout(function() {
            moving = false
        }, 500);
    }

    function moveCarouselTo(slide) {

        // Check if carousel is moving, if not, allow interaction
        if (!moving) {

            // temporarily disable interactivity
            disableInteraction();

            // Preemptively set variables for the current next and previous slide, as well as the potential next or previous slide.
            var newPrevious = slide - 1,
                newNext = slide + 1,
                oldPrevious = slide - 2,
                oldNext = slide + 2;

            // Test if carousel has more than three items
            if ((totalItems - 1) > 3) {

                // Checks if the new potential slide is out of bounds and sets slide numbers
                if (newPrevious <= 0) {
                    oldPrevious = (totalItems - 1);
                } else if (newNext >= (totalItems - 1)) {
                    oldNext = 0;
                }

                // Check if current slide is at the beginning or end and sets slide numbers
                if (slide === 0) {
                    newPrevious = (totalItems - 1);
                    oldPrevious = (totalItems - 2);
                    oldNext = (slide + 1);
                } else if (slide === (totalItems - 1)) {
                    newPrevious = (slide - 1);
                    newNext = 0;
                    oldNext = 1;
                }

                // Now we've worked out where we are and where we're going, by adding and removing classes, we'll be triggering the carousel's transitions.

                // Based on the current slide, reset to default classes.
                items[oldPrevious].className = itemClassName;
                items[oldNext].className = itemClassName;

                // Add the new classes
                items[newPrevious].className = itemClassName + " prev";
                items[slide].className = itemClassName + " active";
                items[newNext].className = itemClassName + " next";
            }
        }
    }

    // Next navigation handler
    function moveNext() {

        // Check if moving
        if (!moving) {

            // If it's the last slide, reset to 0, else +1
            if (slide === (totalItems - 1)) {
                slide = 0;
            } else {
                slide++;
            }

            // Move carousel to updated slide
            moveCarouselTo(slide);
        }
    }

    // Previous navigation handler
    function movePrev() {

        // Check if moving
        if (!moving) {

            // If it's the first slide, set as the last slide, else -1
            if (slide === 0) {
                slide = (totalItems - 1);
            } else {
                slide--;
            }

            // Move carousel to updated slide
            moveCarouselTo(slide);
        }
    }

    // Initialise carousel
    function initCarousel() {
        setInitialClasses();
        setEventListeners();

        // Set moving to false now that the carousel is ready
        moving = false;
    }

    // make it rain
    initCarousel();

}(document));
```

```css
/* Parent wrapper to carousel. Width can be changed as needed. */

.carousel-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.carousel-custom-section {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.carousel-single-item {
    width: 33%;
    display: flex;
}

.carousel-single-item-row {
    display: flex;
    width: 33%;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.carousel-wrapper * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.carousel__photo {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1rem 4rem;
    z-index: 100;
    /* transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s, z-index .5s; */
}

.carousel__photo.initial,
.carousel__photo.active {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 900;
}

.carousel__photo.prev,
.carousel__photo.next {
    z-index: 800;
}


/* Style navigation buttons to sit in the middle, either side of the carousel. */

.carousel__button--prev,
.carousel__button--next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: #FFF;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.carousel__button--prev {
    left: 0;
}

.carousel__button--next {
    right: 0;
}


/* Use pseudo elements to insert arrows inside of navigation buttons */

.carousel__button--prev::after,
.carousel__button--next::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 54%;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
}

.carousel__button--next::after {
    left: 47%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
    <div class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-custom-section">
                <div class="carousel-single-item">
                    <img class="carousel__photo initial" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=one">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-single-item">
                    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/808080?text=two">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-single-item">
                    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FF00/808080?text=three">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-custom-section">
                <div class="carousel-single-item">
                    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/808080?text=four">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-single-item">
                    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FF00/808080?text=five">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-single-item">
                    <img class="carousel__photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FF00/808080?text=six">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel__button--next"></div>
            <div class="carousel__button--prev"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Can somebody please point me in right direction what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give me an existing pen URL?

Comment: Yes sure @EvitaUrbanoviča,  here you go: https://codepen.io/marcusmichaels/pen/yGGoLM

Comment: Any luck with this by any chance? :)

Comment: I suggest giving this code up, try using JavaScript ES6 (http://es6-features.org), here is the what you're looking for, but only in ES6 https://codepen.io/Nathan_James/pen/BvNLzO

Comment: Ok thank you, your example provided works as expected. Only thing it is not working on mobile. Any idea how to get it working on mobile?